Quarto output with gtsummary table - won't render the table when using a loop
I know there are issues with using loops and output of gtsummary tables in quarto. I've tried using
knitr::knit_print(tbl) or cat(knitr::knit_print(tbl)) and can't get that to work either.
I'm basically trying to make several tables looping over different grouping variables. I've made a reproducble example using the titanic dataset below (here trying to make tables splitting by "Survived" and "Sex".
Any help on getting the tables to render in my html quarto output?
If i just run the chunk in rstudio, the tables are fine in my console.
---
title: "titanic data - example"
author: "Me!"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
format:
  html:
    theme: cerulean
    font-size: smaller
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 5
    code-fold: true
    code-tools: true
    code-summary: "Show the code"
    #code-copy: true
comments:
  hypothesis: true
    
editor: visual
---

# knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 6, fig.height = 4) #default size of figs in the doc
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, message = FALSE) # default, suppress warnings & messages

library(titanic)
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)
library(plotrix) # added b/c it has a std.error function
library(tidyverse)

variables <- c("Survived", "Sex")


for (var in variables) {
  tab1 <- titanic_train %>%
    select(!!sym(var), Age, Fare) %>%
    gtsummary::tbl_summary(
      by = !!sym(var), 
      missing = "ifany", # adds a row with number of missing, if any are missing
      statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({std.error})",                   
      digits = all_continuous() ~ 1
    ) %>%
    modify_header(all_stat_cols(FALSE) ~ ("**{level}**<br>N =  {n}")) %>%
    bold_labels() %>%
modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ glue::glue("**Titanic split by - {var}**")) %>%
    add_p(
      test = everything() ~ "oneway.test",
      test.args = all_tests("aov") ~ list(var.equal = TRUE)
    ) %>% gtsummary::as_gt()

print(tab1)
}



does this work if you switch the document type to an rmd? I am just curious to see if it is a quarto issue or gtsummary issue, you may have to add in a results = "as is" into the chunk option?

Agree with Mike regarding asis. Check out https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html#tips

Amazing - that fixed it!!
Just made the code chunk as follows:  {r, results = 'asis'}
